# How to approach variable image sizes for Image Classification?

Tags: python, image-processing, machine-learning, classification, multiclass-classification

I am working on classification of brain tumors. The dataset is comprised of brain images from various angles, with a border and mask of the tumor position. I have cropped the rectangle that contains the tumor, as the other parts of the image are irrelevant and vary due to the different angles from which the image is taken. Now I am left with a series of images of the tumor, each belonging to 1 of 3 possible cases of tumor. But to train this data for classification, I need to have the 2d image array in a uniform shape I believe.

Possible approaches:

1) Crop each image to a fixed size (say 100x100). But this would result in loss of data and also depending on position of the tumor in image, I could be facing uneven crops due to reaching the edge of the image.

2) Pad the image to a fixed shape, bigger than the biggest cropped image shape (say 350x350). But again this would introduce noise in the data I suppose, and I'm not sure how can I pad the image uniformly across all 4 sides of the rectangle.

As these don't seem viable, I'm looking for other solutions to tackle this problem.

Comment: Larger resolution would be better but how many images do you have and what are their resolution before and after cropping? If you have thousands of images larger resolution will require a lot of GPU to normalize and training could be slow.

Comment: @Suleiman I have 3064 images. The shape of the cropped tumor image varies from around (15, 15) to (350, 300)

Comment: 15x15 is quite small in dimension to extract useful features, what machine learning algorithm are you using for classification?

Comment: @SuleimanVery few images will actually be that small though. The mean shape is (75, 75). I will be trying out various classification algorithms and present a study of which performs the best. So I'll start with SVM, Decision Trees and CNN.

Comment: OK, in that case I guess 100x100 might be a good size to start with and then if possible experiment with larger and smaller sizes to see if performance improves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common approach is to crop the tumor on each image. You will obtain different tumor image size. Then rescale the tumor images to the smallest one. Choose wisely the resampling technic for the rescale depending on the algorithm you will use for classification. The fastest one would be nearest neighborhood resampling, a smoother one would be linear interpolation, the ultimate one can be spline interpolation.

Comment: Yes, this seems like the best approach, I'll likely scale all to the mean shape.